# Private Maven Repository in Closed Network

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, nexus

I am in a closed network, do not have access to http://repo.maven.apache.org We set up a Nexus server and we download all of our .m2's on a publicly accessible computer, burn to disk, then upload to our Nexus server (inefficient but necessary)

Currently I am trying to set up the system to only use my nexus server, currently it tries to go to http://repo.maven.apache.org
 (assuming  is set to false) If I have  set to true, it does not even attempt to go to my private repo. Basically, I just need my Maven to only look at my nexus instance, not even attempt to go to http://repo.maven.apache.org

Here are portions of my settings.xml and pom.xml files:

```
<!-- Settings.xml in my .m2 directory -->
<offline>true</offline>
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>mynexus</id>
        <username>xxx</username>
        <password>xxx</username>
    </server>
    <server>
        <id>mynexusplugins</id>
        <username>xxx</username>
        <password>xxx</username>
    </server>
</servers>


<!-- pom.xml -->
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>mynexus</id>
        <url>http://192.168.100.4:8081/....</url>
    </repository>
</repository>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>mynexusplugins</id>
        <url>http://192.168.100.4:8081/....</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepository>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your repository as mirror of all in the settings.xml, this way it won't look any other repo.

```
 <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>yourRepo</id>
      <name>yourRepo name</name>
      <url>your url</url>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
```

https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html

As a side note, If you set offline in maven(via command line or config) it will only use local m2 folder.