# dependency-check-maven plugin: Configure company Nexus

Tags: java, maven

From our company network, we cannot contact MavenCentral, but have a company Nexus. I try to configure the dependency-check-maven plugin to use it, but with no luck. My approach is to set

```
<nexusUrl>http://someIp:8084/nexus/service/local</nexusUrl>
```

but either I need further configurations or the subpath (after `someIp:8084/nexus`) is incorrect. The plugin still tries to contact MavenCentral, waits and fails.

What do I need to do?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49286700/5210117

Comment: @SilverShroud This does not seem to be about the _dependency-maven-plugin_.

Comment: It is global configuration which will affect everything (including dependency plugin) in maven commands. If you want specific solution to dependency plugin, it is no this.

Comment: I am sorry, I meant the _dependency-check-maven-plugin_ (as in the heading). This plugin seems to be unaffected by the configuration because I already have settings.xml pointing to Nexus, everything works fine except for the dependency-check-maven-plugin.

Comment: I just learned this plugins existance today. there is  a centralAnalyzerEnabled configuration try setting it to false. Also in order to work with nexus, pro version is required(nexus oss does not work according to their page)